# ASP.NET MVC 5, INSERT not work in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My job is to make a website for a school management system. I have students and admins who can log in the system. Students can register. I have created controller for ASP.NET MVC 5 using template for Entity Framework. It have created Account model, Controller and Create, Delete, Details, Edit, Index views. Fields of account are:

```
public int AccountID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> TypeID { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string ICNumber { get; set; }
public string Telephone { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
public string Adress { get; set; }`
```

I have changed my views to hide information that does not need to shown, as ID, password etc.  (My code =>)

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}
@model WebApplication9.Account


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Account</h4>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeID, "TypeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("TypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ICNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ICNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ICNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Adress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Account ID should be autogenereted in database, I have also used Identity as StoreGenerated Pattern in Account Model but Im getting error while trying to registrate new student:

> SQLException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AccountID'

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register([Bind(Include = "AccountID,TypeID,Password,FirstName,LastName,ICNumber,Telephone,email,Adress")] Account account)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Accounts.Add(account);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.TypeID = new SelectList(db.AccountTypes, "TypeID", "TypeName", account.TypeID);
        return View(account);
    }
```

Comment: Try putting the data attribute `[Key]` above your `AccountID` property in your `Account` model.  Also would be helpful to know if you are using Code First or Database First.

Comment: On another note, not sure how far into development you are but ASP.NET MVC 5 has Identity and it is a great way to start off with user accounts and authentication.  Does a lot of the stuff for you and you don't have to worry about all the nuances of authentication like salting and hashing passwords.

Comment: @David Lee Database First

Comment: Try adding the `[Key]` attribute and make sure your database is setup as an auto incremented field.  You could also remove the `AccountID` from your `[Bind(Include = "")]` as this is not being set by the post and being managed on the server.

Comment: @DavidLee I know about it, but have problems with connecting it to my own database, so I decided to make my own verification, and everything work fine except registration.

Comment: On your SQL Server the `AccountID` should be set to Yes for Identity Specification and (Is Identity) should  be Yes.  Identity Increment is usually 1 and identity seed is usually 1 but those should not be causing any issues with your insert.

Comment: @DavidLee [Key] worked! Thanks, but now code for Account model and othere models was overwritten after I made some changes in Model.edmx... Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: The Models and edmx have to match in order for your application to properly map to the database.  There may be a way to prevent it but not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Accout Model**

Try adding the `[Key]` attribute and make sure your database is setup as an auto incremented field.

```
[Key]
public int AccountID { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

You could also remove the `AccountID` from your `[Bind(Include = "")]` as this is not being set by the post and being managed on the server.  This should not be causing the error, but would be good practice to do.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register([Bind(Include = "TypeID,Password,FirstName,LastName,ICNumber,Telephone,email,Adress")] Account account)
{
    // stuff
}
```

**SQL Server**

On your SQL Server the `AccountID` should be set to Yes for Identity Specification and (Is Identity) should be Yes. Identity Increment is usually 1 and identity seed is usually 1 but those should not be causing any issues with your insert.

Comment: It helped thanks! But one more problem I found all models are overwritten after I made some changes in Model.edmx... Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: You are welcome, I posted in the comment to your question about the model overwrites.  Not sure if I can help you there.